# Add CSS Class to Link in TinyMCE editor

Tags: links, tinymce

In searching for a solution, I've come across the plugin to enable a dropdown of CSS styles already present within a stylesheet. What I want is to allow the editor to add CSS Classes from a textbox. So if you consider this image:

[image]

What I'm ideally looking for is a way to get another textbox in there below **Title** called *Class*. The freedom to type in a CSS class is needed for other functionality within the site. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the [WP Edit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-edit/) plugin to my site. It has an *Advanced Link* button, that allows me (or an editor) to manually type in a classname.

Comment: Developer of WP Edit here.  Thanks for posting that the plugin helped you.  Please let me know if you have any questions regarding usage.

Comment: Hey thanks josh! Just started using it so I'll let you know. So far, so good!

Answer (score 22):

One option is to add a class to the Styleselect menu in MCE. Adapted from the ["TinyMCE Custom Styles" Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles) you first need to add the style select to the editor:

```
// Callback function to insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
// Register our callback to the appropriate filter
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');
```

That will add the new drop down to the editor. Then you create your custom styles:

```
// Callback function to filter the MCE settings
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  
    // Define the style_formats array
    $style_formats = array(  
        // Each array child is a format with it's own settings
        array(  
            'title' => 'My Link Custom Class',  
            'selector' => 'a',  
            'classes' => 'my-custom-link-class'             
        )
    );  
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );  

    return $init_array;  

} 
// Attach callback to 'tiny_mce_before_init' 
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

As of WordPress 3.9 which included an upgrade to TinyMCE 4.0, the style select is much more robust and includes that `selector` rule that means you can define styles that only can be applied to links. It's pretty nice.

This solution means you can pre-define the classes you need and ensure there are never typos or other problems.

As the Codex notes, this is best combined with a good [`editor-style.css` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) that will apply your styles directly in the editor.

Comment: Hi mrwweb. Thanks for your reply, although not quite what I was looking for. I don't intend to select a class from a predefined list of classes. Instead, I just need to allow the editor to type out a classname. Basically, I've used the Lime Modal plugin from CodeCanyon, and this requires that the trigger link uses a classname that is the same as the modal unique name.

Comment: This is very interesting, I like this method, but is there any way to add the new option in with the other drop down items (i.e. paragraph, heading 1, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure, @rev. One thing I like is that this strategy generally allows you to separate semantic HTML elements from class-driven CSS styles (that are hopefully still semantic). I don't have time to do this right now, but just try `var_dump()`ing the `$init_array` above and see what's there. Remember that the TinyMCE 4.0 update in WordPress 3.9 made a lot of existing tutorials and documentation wrong. Check dates when researching.

Comment: Ah, I see the benefit in keeping it separate. I just kind of hesitate in adding a whole new drop down just to add one new class, haha. I'll look in to your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I hear you. [When I do this](https://gist.github.com/mrwweb/9937127) I remove the `formatselect` and switch completely to `styleselect` for all block elements and text styles.